# Multiple SELECT in NHibernate native SQL

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate

I create a complex search query in native SQL. It's basically something like this:

```
SELECT ID FROM t_Product WHERE Name LIKE @criteria
SELECT publisher, count(*) as number FROM t_Product GROUP BY publisher
```

It has 2 `SELECT` statements and I want it to be sent to DB server in one round trip.

But I can't figure out how to achieve this in Nhibernate.

I considered following options but none seems to work

1. Use `CreateMultiQuery`, but this only accept HQL, not native SQL
2. Use `CreateSQLQuery`, but call to List() only return result for the first `SELECT` statement
3. Moving to a stored procedure is not an option since the whole SQL is very dynamic.
4. We still use Nhibernate 1.2 thus new features in later version couldn't be used either.

Advice are welcome.

Comment: why are you against writing it in HQL?

Answer (score 1):

Not possible using NH version 1.2

Futures was released in version 2.1 which allows you to do exactly this.

e.g.

```
var blogs = s.CreateCriteria<Invoice>()
  .SetMaxResults(30)
  .Future<Invoice>();
var countOfInvoices = s.CreateCriteria<Invoice>()
  .SetProjection(Projections.Count(Projections.Id()))
  .FutureValue<int>();
```

So you are going to either upgrade, fall back to ADO.NET and use multiple recordsets or live with what you have! Sorry!

Comment: I did some test using NH3.2 and it appears Futures doesn't support native SQL either. I guess that's because it is built on top of Multi query

Comment: HQL, QueryOver and ICriteria are all supported. Never tried with native SQL to be honest

Comment: As a side note the SQL examples you showed us can be converted to HQL quite simply, but I suspect you have more complex SQL!

Answer (score 1):

This is really going to be scenario-specific, but if you're stuck with NH Version 1.2, and eliminating the round-trip is your goal, you could consider rewriting this as a single query using a sub-select.

Something along the lines of:

```
SELECT publisher, count(*) as number, 
(SELECT ID FROM t_Product WHERE Name LIKE @criteria) As theId 
FROM t_Product GROUP BY publisher
```

Would work if your subquery only returned a single value.

Comment: Thanks, you gives me another way of thinking. Let me try if I can change my query as you suggested.

Comment: One other caveat I should have mentioned, your "outer" query will always need to return at least a single row for the subselect query to return a result, so ensure you plan for that :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it is possible, because both queries are SELECTs.

You may try a semicolon after the first query, and two line feeds between them, this is required for some databases. I successfully run query-scripts like this. If it runs, use a debugger to see what you get back ...

If this doesn't work, you need separate round trips or switch to HQL / Criteria.

Comment: As I expected: I don't think that it works. Use HQL/Criteria or two round trips.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MultiQuery "Hack" like this:

The procudure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_Name]
AS BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM t_Question where ...
    SELECT * FROM t_Question where ........
END
```

The NHibernate Query Code:

```
public void ProcdureMultiTableQuery()
{
    var session = Session;
    var procSQLQuery = session.CreateSQLQuery("exec [proc_Name] ?,?");// prcodure returns two table
    procSQLQuery.SetParameter(0, userId);
    procSQLQuery.SetParameter(1, page);
    procSQLQuery.AddEntity(typeof(Question));

    var multiResults = session.CreateMultiQuery()
        .Add(procSQLQuery)
        // More table your procedure returns,more empty SQL query you should add
        .Add(session.CreateSQLQuery(" ").AddEntity(typeof(Question))) // the second table returns Question Model
        .List();
    if (multiResults == null || multiResults.Count == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    if (multiResults.Count != 2)
    {
        return;
    }
    var questions1 = ConvertObjectsToArray<Question>((System.Collections.IList)multiResults[0]);
    var questions2 = ConvertObjectsToArray<Question>((System.Collections.IList)multiResults[1]);
}

static T[] ConvertObjectsToArray<T>(System.Collections.IList objects)
{
    if (objects == null || objects.Count == 0)
    {
        return null;
    }
    var array = new T[objects.Count];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        array[i] = (T)objects[i];
    }
    return array;
}
```